# How to do "nested" expects in Jest, or validate rejects with multiple expects

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I find myself wanting to do multiple validations on a rejected promise result.

So far the only way I have found to do this is by "hacking" `toSatisfy`:

```
    await expect(axios.get('<some call that throws a 40x error')).rejects.toSatisfy((axiosError) => {
      expect(axiosError.response?.status).toBe(400);
      expect(axiosError.response?.data).toHaveProperty('message');
      expect(
        (
          axiosError.response?.data as {
            message: string;
          }
        ).message
      ).toMatch(/invalid period.*/);
      return true;
    });
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

As you can see it's a little clunky as I have to `return true` at the end and it's not fluent as I'm not using `toSatisfy` as it's supposed to be used.

Comment: Seems like you could just do `.rejects.toMatchObject({ status: 400, ... })`, no? The maintainers have rejected chaining multiple assertions on a value so _"not fluent"_ is to be expected: [jestjs/jest#3998](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/3998).

Comment: thanks - that issue is helpful. Quite disappointed that chaining didn't get in. I'll have a go at using the extension.

Comment: Or, given that you want a fluent interface and appear to be making a request and asserting on the response: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a `.catch`?

The only drawback is that you should specify the total number of assertations in advance, which serves the purpose of failing the test if not all `expect`s pass before timeout. This is a more semantic way than `toSatisfy` in my opinion.

```
 it('Test promise rejection', async () => {
    expect.assertions(3);
    await axios.get('<some call that throws a 40x error')
      .catch(axiosError => {
         expect(axiosError.response?.status).toBe(400);
         expect(axiosError.response?.data).toHaveProperty('message');
         expect(
           (
             axiosError.response?.data as {
               message: string;
             }
           ).message
        ).toMatch(/invalid period.*/);
      });
 });
```

Comment: Returning `true` doesn't signal Jest to stop waiting for [`toVerify`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/toSatisfy), it isn't an asynchronous matcher. Whether the assertion is considered to have passed or failed is determined from the truthiness of the return value. The assertions also in that callback are really just a side effect, hence the OP's description of it as "hacking".

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right, edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Yeah  - thanks. Not much different to try/catch though and defoes don't want to rely on "expect.assertions(3)" for test validation. Will have a look at the chaining extension.